# How to upload a PDF to Access database?

Tags: ms-access

I have 100+ pdf files that I would like to load into an access database. When the pdf is uploaded, I would like for the data retrieved to update in an access form. How to do that?

Comment: You are very brave :-)

Comment: What exactly is your problem here?

Comment: You want Access to read the data in the PDF file?

Comment: See http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/attach-files-and-graphics-to-the-records-in-your-database-HA001213852.aspx